# Project Planning

Tags: project-planning

Does anyone know of an article or could give me some tips to follow when creating a new web project?

This project is for myself in my spare time, and not for a client.

Comment: How to get started with a web project - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737719/how-to-get-started-with-web-development

Answer (score 4):

This guy has made some really good articles about it.

[Pragmatic Web Project Planning Part 1](http://www.thesambarnes.com/web-project-management/web-project-planning/pragmatic-web-project-planning-part-1-of-3/)

[Pragmatic Web Project Planning Part 2](http://www.thesambarnes.com/web-project-management/web-project-planning/pragmatic-web-project-planning-part-2-of-3/)

[Pragmatic Web Project Planning Part 3](http://www.thesambarnes.com/web-project-management/web-project-planning/pragmatic-web-project-planning-part-3-of-3/)

The rest of his blog is also worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks great articles , Thanks alot.

Comment: this is really a great series on planning articles

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful - [Finding Inspiration When Starting a New Web Project](http://www.fuelyourcreativity.com/finding-inspiration-when-starting-a-new-web-project-your-first-steps-into-uncharted-territory/)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should know who your customer is. what is their needs? then try to list what should be displayed one your website. [wireframing](http://jatinangor2010.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/denah-lokasi-it1.png) also give you a clear visual of your webs.then build it ! :D 
regards.